# Apply function in pandas with multiple args and multiple outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function `foo()` which takes two arguments as two columns of pandas named year and month and return a list of four numbers.

```
  df['A'],df['B'],df['C'],df['D']=  df.apply(lambda x: foo(x.year, x.month), axis=1,result_type="expand")
```

It just gives me four columns named A,B,C,D with 0,1,2,3 respectively filled in them. What am I doing wrong?

Kindly don't answer for single variable outputs or single variable arguments. There are plenty of examples out there for that.
Thankyou so much for the help.

Comment: Can you add more part of function and data examples so that we can recreate the environment you are working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assigning the results of `df.apply` with optional parameter `result_type='expand'`, instead, Use:

```
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] =  df.apply(lambda x: foo(x.year, x.month), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Consider the example demonstrating this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(5), 'col2': np.arange(5) * 2})

#print(df)
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     4     8
```

Reproducing the problem situation,

```
df['A'], df['B'] = df.apply(lambda s: (s['col1']**2, s['col2']**2), axis=1, result_type='expand')

#print(df)
   col1  col2  A  B
0     0     0  0  1
1     1     2  0  1
2     2     4  0  1
3     3     6  0  1
4     4     8  0  1
```

---

The solution is,

```
df[['A', 'B']] = df.apply(lambda s: (s['col1']**2, s['col2']**2), axis=1, result_type='expand')

#print(df)
   col1  col2   A   B
0     0     0   0   0
1     1     2   1   4
2     2     4   4  16
3     3     6   9  36
4     4     8  16  64
```

OR:

```
df['A'], df['B'] = df.apply(
lambda s: (s['col1']**2, s['col2']**2), axis=1, result_type='expand').T.to_numpy()

#print(df)
   col1  col2   A   B
0     0     0   0   0
1     1     2   1   4
2     2     4   4  16
3     3     6   9  36
4     4     8  16  64
```

Comment: Can you explain a little what the difference is? And why was mine giving 0,1,2,3?

Comment: Well, I guess if you try to unpack the results of `.apply` with `result_type='expand` it just returns the headers of newly created columns (I guess its internal implementation behaviour).

Comment: @jazrael @anky Can you explain about the behaviour of `result_type=expand` used here? Why its returning headers when we try to unpack it?

Comment: When you unpack a dataframe , it by default chooses to return column headers example: `print(list(df))` would return column names, for accessing the values you need to access the underlying array you need to use `.to_numpy()` : `df['col3'],df['col4'] =  df.apply(lambda s: (s['col1']**2, s['col2']**2), axis=1, result_type='expand').T.to_numpy()`

Comment: you can also replicate by unpacking a dictionary `[*{"a":1,"b":2}]` which returns the keys since that is the first iterable it finds , with your solution, it doesnot have to unpack rather assign to the dataframe :) nice catch though(upvoted)

Comment: @anky Makes sense.:),  btw, Thanks for taking time out for explaining.